# How to increase number of Call Stack entries in Google Chrome Developer Tools (or Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

How to increase number of Call Stack entries in Google Chrome Developer Tools (or Firefox Firebug)? I am getting a Javascript error in a third party control's Javascript. All the calls in the Call Stack window do not belong to my own code. I want to know which line in my code triggered the sequence of events. The Call Stack is not large enough to display something from my own code.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the earliest call, can you see what came before it?

Comment: For testing you can try to up the js stack size: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1631

Answer (score 32):

### Chrome solution

https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api

can set via commandline on startup `--js-flags="--stack-trace-limit <value>"`

or at runtime at loading a page: `Error.stackTraceLimit=undefined //unlimited stack trace`

Comment: Can you please show the full command?  I tried `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --js-flags="--stack-trace-limit 50"` but the stack trace still stops at 10

Comment: if you open chrome dev console you can just type '''Error.stackTraceLimit'''  and it will show you the current value.   you can then modify it as you wish.

Comment: such as ```Error.stackTraceLimit=50```

Comment: Setting the `Error.stackTraceLim‌​it` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @NoNameProvided set to Infinity instead.

Comment: On Windows, where do I pass these parameters to Chrome? I mean, the "--js-flags" ones? Google Chrome is not a global variable that I can access from the command prompt. Do I need to add it to the path?

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to be able to change this at runtime? I imagine an advertisement page blocking your laptop/phone because of an infinite loop

Comment: Setting the `Error.stackTraceLim‌​it` property works on Chrome 60. Running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Setting it to 50 worked for me today in Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (Mac OS El Capitan 64-bit)

Answer (score 19):

In Chrome (also in node), you can type this in the js console:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
```

Alternatively see this page for Chrome command line flags: https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api (need to restart Chrome):

```
$ google-chrome --js-flags="--stack-trace-limit 10000"
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's a limit on call stack size*). Usually a stack trace that seems to come out of nowhere results from either

- an event listener
- a timeout (`window.setTimeout`)
- an interval (`window.setInterval`)
- some script loading after page has loaded (possibly iframe)

<sub>*) Of course, technically there certainly is some limit, but I gues it's practically irrelevant. Probably longint or something.</sub>

---

edit: From [Firebug source code](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.9/content/firebug/js/stackFrame.js?r=12518#62):

```
    if (trace.frames.length > 100)  // TODO in the loop above
    {
        var originalLength = trace.frames.length;
        trace.frames.splice(50, originalLength - 100);
        var excuse = "(eliding "+(originalLength - 100)+" frames)";

        trace.frames[50] = new StackFrame.StackFrame({href: excuse}, 0, excuse,
            [], null, null, context);
     }
```

So Firebug will always show the first 50 and the last 50 items ("frames") of the call stack.

Comment: You are wrong. There is a maximum stack size and it is very important. Not for stuff written in an async way - but more e.g. for interpreters. I ran into this problem with Chrome (has a far smaller maximum stack size than Firefox has) when having a Lisp interpreter. Mostly in the end the best thing to do is to change your JavaScript so it runs asynchronously (and to slice the processing via `setTimeout`). That said - for a third party script I do not really have a good idea how to solve it.