# How can I get more stacktrace in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, exception

I'm using the decorator to change the `$exceptionHandler` behavior, sending logs to the server. My problem with this is that the stackatrace of the exceptions seems useless, showing only part of the stack. For example:

> Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column NaN
>   of the expression [expression here].
>
> ```
> at Error (native)
> at throwError (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6674:62)
> at primary (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6918:9)
> at unary (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6900:14)
> at multiplicative (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6883:16)
> at additive (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6874:16)
> at relational (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6865:16)
> at equality (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6856:16)
> at logicalAND (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6847:16)
> at logicalOR (http://localhost:8080/angular/angular.js:6839:41)
> ```

Is there some way to configure AngularJS to show more stacks? If I look at Chrome console, I can see more stack, and get the filename, but not in the exception handler.

Even if I change the `Error` limit I cannot see the original file:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
```

Comment: There is no known way to do this.

Comment: I was at Ng-Conf this winter and the angular team had a presentation on zone.js. I haven't looked into it so I don't know how relevant but perhaps worth exploring. http://thechangelog.com/zone-js/ (that is not my blog btw, just googled it up)

Comment: @ivarni Sounds really interesting, unfortunately I cannot change the architecture of the project :{

Comment: Are you throwing the error using 'throw new Error("error description")', or 'throw "error description"'? If you throw an Error object, it has more information available.

Comment: @AlexanderMarquardt I didn't tried with a custom error, just catching the Angular ones.

Comment: Can you provide here your implementation of $exceptionHandler decorator ?

Comment: Have you tried the solutionS described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931444/how-to-increase-number-of-call-stack-entries-in-google-chrome-developer-tools-o

Comment: @Sphaso I just tried `Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity`. I don't know if undefined will work differently.

Comment: @SérgioMichels only one way to find out... but why "undefined"? I was actually referring to this: google-chrome --js-flags="--stack-trace-limit 10000"

Comment: thats one part of angular that really sucks....stack-traces are useless more than often

Comment: @Dawn: so true, damn.. :/

Answer (score 3):

### 1 Use a  debugger, instead of Chrome console

Google Chrome provides a debugger that helps JS programmers to find bugs and problematic code.

> As the complexity of JavaScript applications increase, developers need
>   powerful debugging tools to help quickly discover the cause of a
>   issue and fix it efficiently. The Chrome DevTools include several
>   useful tools to help make debugging JavaScript less painful.

You can try putting some breakpoints wherever you want (try to detect the problematic lines/ methods).

See the official documentation here: [Google Chrome Debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

### 2 Use a browser extension

Many plugins like [ng-inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en) or [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) helps you to print the status of your AngularJS program (controller instances, variable names/values, and scopes).

### 3 Use $log service (console.log wrapper)

The AngularJS $log service provides a simple resource to print the status of your variables in the browser console (if present).

> Simple service for logging. Default implementation safely writes the
>   message into the browser's console (if present).
>
> The main purpose of this service is to simplify debugging and
>   troubleshooting.
>
> The default is to log debug messages. You can use
>   ng.$logProvider#debugEnabled to change this. AngularJS $log service
>   helps you to debug your program.

---

From my point of view, a good AngularJS debug includes the combination of all the above solutions.

I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: The lack of stack trace makes debugging tools useless. If the OP knew the line number to place the breakpoint, I don't think he would be asking this question.

Comment: I'm not downvoting this answer because it still has useful information, but it doesn't really address the question.  I also need a longer stack trace to determine what line in *my* code is generating the error.  I suppose I might be able to use the debugger to step all the way back up to my code, but that feels pretty inefficient.

Comment: @rinogo Have you found a way to do this yet? I hate that I can't find what line of my code is causing the error

Comment: @Amon - I got nothin for ya.  I think I just resorted to old-school “debugging” techniques like commenting out sections of code and placing calls to console.log throughout the code in question to hone in on the problem. Sorry I can’t help more!

Comment: @rinogo It's okay! I'm using the breakpoints in the debugger, why don't you use that? I was looking for the origin of an error I was getting in my code, but I actually think it's coming from an extension. According to the breakpoint, does that make sense?

Comment: @Amon yup. One thing I’ve found useful in that scenario is actually hacking up (or adding breakpoints in) the ‘extension’ in ‘node_modules’. You could use breakpoints similarly, I’m guessing!

Comment: @rinogo I see, I did not know that. I've been sitting here confused for so long. In that case can I just ignore the error then? I wouldn't effect my app right?