# How to increase stack trace in chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, stack, stack-trace

It is very difficult to debug when the stacktrace in chrome dev tools is constrained to 10.
The stack trace mostly shows library files, and am unable to see the origin of the error in my js files.
I have tried to increase the stack trace by following - [How to increase number of Call Stack entries in Google Chrome Developer Tools (or Firefox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931444/how-to-increase-number-of-call-stack-entries-in-google-chrome-developer-tools-o)
but it did not work out

Kindly help, specifically how to increse stack trace in mac book

Comment: Setting `Error.stackTraceLimit` in console didn't work for you?

Comment: Nope, it says it would work for that window only...but did not.

Comment: @azium - I actually am looking on how to increase it always, rather than enabling for a session